# Is there any common application for the union of two cartesian products on two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, is there any common application of $({A\times B})\cup(B\times A)$? The two orderings only ever contain similar elements if $A\cap B \neq\emptyset$, so I imagine combing the two could yield something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewed as a relation for A $\cup$ B,
(A×B) $\cup$ (BxA) is the symmetric closure of A×B.

Comment: From my reading, Cartesian products aren't commutative, so the two orderings are different

Comment: Such products are not orders. @user189728

Comment: I edited the answer to make sure there was no ambiguity.   Do you know what the symmetric closure of a relation is? @user189728.

Comment: No, I am very new to this topic